# REST service to access another third party service

Tags: java, angular, model-view-controller

I'm designing a UI application made in Angular.
I also have developed the back-end on Java.

My application access a third party REST service to get some weather data.
That service is paid and I have a key to access it.

I'm trying to integrate that data in my Angular APP.
I've been reading and is not recommendable to store or manage keys on the client side (haven't seen an approach secured enough to avoid having anybody get that key from the client).
So my question is, is imperative to implement the access of that weather data using a back-end service?
Is there a better approach? Like creating a REST service on my application that would work only as a proxy, adding the key, accessing the other third party REST service and returning the same raw data?

Would be ideal for me to implement that directly on the UI, but I'm concern about how to deal with the security.

Comment: Yep, you just want to create a proxy in effect.

Comment: You can setup the proxy in your backend and everybody wins.

Comment: Well, I will just reinforce that you should not put your keys in the client side, specially with your note that the "service is paid". doing that will expose your keys to the internet, crawlers will most definitely find it and is likely to cause harm if other people start to use it, specially when quotas is something you paid for.

Comment: About your proxy, you would like to set your data for your pages in the back end and not use calls from the client side to get it. However, if this is a functionality that involves real time update or AJAX, you would be wise to start by protecting through CORS.

Comment: CORS is not enough as your proxy will still be accessible to clients that are not web browsers or are a misbehaved browsers. To address this issue, you would like to issue tokens like those (XSRF/CSRF) tokens you see everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I will just reinforce that you should not put your keys in the client side, specially with your note that the "service is paid". doing that will expose your keys to the internet, crawlers will most definitely find it and is likely to cause harm if other people start to use it, specially when quotas is something you paid for.

About your proxy, you would like to set your data for your pages in the back end and not use calls from the client side to get it. However, if this is a functionality that involves real time updates or AJAX, you would be wise to start by protecting through CORS.

CORS is not enough, however, as your proxy will still be accessible to clients that are not web browsers or are misbehaved browsers. To address this issue, you would like to issue tokens like those (XSRF/CSRF) tokens you see everywhere.

Button line, the key elements for your question are:

- Do not put keys in your UI layer
- Building a proxy service will not protect them if this service is open
- Not knowing your keys will not keep anyone from using them, if your usage is not secure as well; e.g., accessing your service to get the data, or composing web pages with parts of your page - served by your server